# MediaElement plays video, but no video shows

Tags: wpf, windows-xp, mediaelement

I can open a video, play it and get position and set position, but nothing shows up in the video window on one pc. The code works fine a on a couple of PCs, but doesn't work on another. Does any one know or can refer me to what files I need to properly run MediaElement on XP pro.

Thanks,
Rob

Comment: You're not running it through citrix, remote desktop or something like this, are you?

Comment: I agree with your comment.  I've had no luck displaying video in a MediaElement over a remote desktop connection, even though it plays fine in Media Player over RDC.

See here for more http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/758491/video-doesn-not-play-on-rdp-when-playing-inside-wpf-application-works-fine-in-wmp

Answer (score 0):

You need at least Windows Media Player 10 or above to be able to use MediaElement properly. A default installation of Win XP doesn't include that. Vista and Win 7 does, however.

Comment: I've found anything less than Media Player 11 fails to play pretty much anything.

Comment: What about Silverlight? I have a MediaElement on my page - surely it doesn't require Media Player 10?

Answer (score 0):

What media files you are trying to playback? To play the non just wmv files in WPF you need to have a codecs installed.

Your behavior is very strange and I have similar problem but only when WPF player have been played for a many hours and video renderer stops render the video w/o any error reporting.

I could advise you to install the codecs (or re-install, if you have them already installed). Try to use ffdshow + Haali Media Splitter. This combination allows me to play any media type. And do not install the K-Lite Codec Pack, seems I have my own problem with freezing media because of using it.